# How can I get a file's ctime, atime, mtime and change them

Tags: file, go

How can I get file's ctime, mtime, atime use Go and change them?

In Go 1.1.2,
* os.Stat can only get mtime
* os.Chtimes can change mtime and atime but not ctime.

Comment: @wheaties That seems like a particularly unhelpful comment, given that this is not an algorithmic problem but a matter of finding the right syscall API.

Comment: @TimPierce: If it's really "a matter of finding the right syscall API" then what is it? What is your evidence for that claim?

Comment: In general, you can't update `ctime` on UNIX systems.  It is automatically updated every time the file's metadata changes, so would be reset if there was a call to change it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Linux
>
> [ctime](http://www.linux-faqs.info/general/difference-between-mtime-ctime-and-atime)
>
> ctime is the inode or file change time. The ctime gets updated when
>   the file attributes are changed, like changing the owner, changing the
>   permission or moving the file to an other filesystem but will also be
>   updated when you modify a file.

The file ctime and atime are OS dependent. For Linux, ctime is set by Linux to the current timestamp when the inode or file is changed.

Here's an example, on Linux, of implicitly changing ctime by setting atime and mtime to their original values.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func statTimes(name string) (atime, mtime, ctime time.Time, err error) {
    fi, err := os.Stat(name)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    mtime = fi.ModTime()
    stat := fi.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t)
    atime = time.Unix(int64(stat.Atim.Sec), int64(stat.Atim.Nsec))
    ctime = time.Unix(int64(stat.Ctim.Sec), int64(stat.Ctim.Nsec))
    return
}

func main() {
    name := "stat.file"
    atime, mtime, ctime, err := statTimes(name)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(atime, mtime)
    fmt.Println(ctime)
    err = os.Chtimes(name, atime, mtime)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    atime, mtime, ctime, err = statTimes(name)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(atime, mtime)
    fmt.Println(ctime)
}
```

Output:

```
2014-01-02 02:21:26.262111165 -0500 EST 2014-01-02 02:18:13.253154086 -0500 EST
2014-01-02 02:21:25.666108207 -0500 EST
2014-01-02 02:21:26.262111165 -0500 EST 2014-01-02 02:18:13.253154086 -0500 EST
2014-01-02 02:21:43.814198198 -0500 EST
```

Comment: But the poster's question is: how can a program written in Go retrieve a file's ctime?

Comment: @TimPierce: If you read the question carefully you will see that the question also asked how to change ctime.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is super old but I pulled together the various platform-dependent file access time structs and put them into one package with a unified API:

https://github.com/djherbis/atime

```
package main

import (
  "log"

  "github.com/djherbis/atime"
)

func main() {
  at, err := atime.Stat("myfile")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err.Error())
  }
  log.Println(at)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On a Unix system, you can get a file's mtime and ctime via `syscall.Stat`:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "syscall"
)

func main() {
        var st syscall.Stat_t
        if err := syscall.Stat("/tmp/sysstat.go", &st); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("mtime: %d\n", st.Mtimespec.Sec)
        fmt.Printf("ctime: %d\n", st.Ctimespec.Sec)
}
```

To update these values, you should be able to use `syscall.Utimes`.

Comment: That's the wrong way to do it in Go. Go tries to be OS independent by providing the `OS` package. Don't use the `syscall` package unless it's absolutely necessary, which it isn't here. See my revised answer for how to do this in Go.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's not clear to me how `os.Stat.Sys` is different from `syscall.Stat`. I understand that the role of the `os` package is to provide a platform-independent interface to system calls, but as far as I can tell, the purpose of the `Sys` method is to skip that and go directly to the OS's underlying primitives anyway. So what is gained here?

Comment: @TimPierce The code here doesn't work on windows. Some members of Stat_t have different types on different operating systems, so your code may have to deal with that. Only use syscall.* when you have to.

Comment: @nos Okay, thanks. I was under the impression that the `Sys` interface just gave you access to the low-level primitive filesystem call on whichever platform you're working on, but I see now from the source that that's not the case. I appreciate your help.