# Is there a way to set `mtime` while preserving `atime` with the `os` module?

Tags: go

Is there any way to set just the `mtime` on a file with `os.Chtimes` ? I thought I could pass a modified `mtime` along with an unmodified `atime` to `Chtimes`, but the `FileInfo` returned by `os.Stat` only gives you `mtime`, via `os.FileInfo.ModTime()`.

It seems odd that `os.Chtimes` requires changing both `atime` and `mtime` at once, but there is no way to retrieve `atime` from the provided `os` functions.

this is related to [How can I get a file's ctime,atime,mtime and change them using Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875336/how-can-i-get-a-files-ctime-atime-mtime-and-change-them-using-golang) , but I'd like to set less information.

Answer (score 2):

This allows you to modify `mtime`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    name := "main"
    atime, mtime, ctime, err := statTimes(name)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(atime, mtime, ctime)

    // new mtime
    newMtime := time.Date(2000, time.February, 1, 3, 4, 5, 0, time.UTC)

    // set new mtime
    err = os.Chtimes(name, atime, newMtime)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    atime, mtime, ctime, err = statTimes(name)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(atime, mtime, ctime)
}

func statTimes(name string) (atime, mtime, ctime time.Time, err error) {
    fi, err := os.Stat(name)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    mtime = fi.ModTime()
    stat := fi.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t)
    atime = time.Unix(int64(stat.Atim.Sec), int64(stat.Atim.Nsec))
    ctime = time.Unix(int64(stat.Ctim.Sec), int64(stat.Ctim.Nsec))
    return
}
```

and get atime, ctime from fi.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t)

```
stat := fi.Sys().(*syscall.Stat_t)
atime = time.Unix(int64(stat.Atim.Sec), int64(stat.Atim.Nsec))
ctime = time.Unix(int64(stat.Ctim.Sec), int64(stat.Ctim.Nsec))
```

I know that the file systems of various operating systems are different.
Commonly used parts are defined in os.Fileinfo as below. https://golang.org/search?q=os.FileInfo

```
// A FileInfo describes a file and is returned by Stat and Lstat.
type FileInfo interface {
    Name() string       // base name of the file
    Size() int64        // length in bytes for regular files; system-dependent for others
    Mode() FileMode     // file mode bits
    ModTime() time.Time // modification time
    IsDir() bool        // abbreviation for Mode().IsDir()
    Sys() interface{}   // underlying data source (can return nil)
}
```

A fileStat is the implementation of FileInfo. The fileStat is declared differently for each os. https://golang.org/search?q=fileStat

linux, unix actually uses the following struct.

```
// A fileStat is the implementation of FileInfo returned by Stat and Lstat.
type fileStat struct {
    name    string
    size    int64
    mode    FileMode
    modTime time.Time
    sys     syscall.Stat_t
}
```

and Obtain ctime and atime from syscall.Stat_t.

Comment: Thanks. That looks a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/a/20877193/5556676 . Can you comment on the portability of this solution, or indicate why `os` doesn't let you read atime, but allows you to set it?

Comment: I know that the file systems of various operating systems are different. Commonly used parts are defined in os.Fileinfo as below. update post.